# How do I make a F# SQLProvider source file (.fs)?

Tags: sql-server, f#

MY F# SQLProvider code that works in a script file, fails when copied into a source file. Specifically, it seems like there is no communication with the server because the intellisense that allows me to see available tables, columns, etc. in the .fsx file; doesn't work in the .fs file. I have the FSharp.Data.SqlProvider referenced in my solution, and opened in the code block, but the properties for the GetDataContext() method are MIA. The project references FSharp Core 4.6.0.

```
module DBaseTest

open FSharp.Data.Sql

let [<Literal>] connectionString = "Data Source=####;Initial Catalog=####;etc.;etc."

type sql = SqlDataProvider<
           DatabaseVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER,
           CaseSensitivityChange = Common.CaseSensitivityChange.ORIGINAL,
           ConnectionString = connectionString,
           IndividualsAmount = 1000,
           UseOptionTypes = true>

let tables = sql.GetDataContext().Dbo  <--Dbo unrecognized in the .fs file
```

I also tried starting a new console application using .Net 4.5.1 (FSharp Core 4.5.2) with the same error. The GetDataContext method doesn't have any properties (tables, columns, etc.), and the file won't compile.

```
open System
open FSharp.Data.Sql

let [<Literal>] connectionString = "Data Source=###;Initial Catalog=###;..."

type sql = SqlDataProvider<
            DatabaseVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER,
            CaseSensitivityChange = Common.CaseSensitivityChange.ORIGINAL,
            ConnectionString = connectionString,
            IndividualsAmount = 1000,
            UseOptionTypes = true>

let table = sql.GetDataContext().Dbo  //property Dbo not found

let testQuery =
    query{
        for rows in table.Organization do
        where (rows.OrgName = "ASME")
        select rows
    } |> Seq.toArray

let firstRow = testQuery.[0].PressureLabel

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" firstRow
    Console.Read() |> ignore
    0
```

Comment: In what way does it die?  Does it compile ok but throw an exception at runtime?

Comment: @Foole:  The intellisense acts like there's no properties for the GetDataContext method. i.e. The database's tables and their columns and keys don't show up. If I try to build it anyway, it errors out on those same unrecognized properties. In the above snippet, the ". dbo" is red underlined in V.Studio.

Comment: Try adding references to `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` and `System.Configuration`

Comment: @KonstantinKonstantinov: I installed / added both references with no change after restarting the solution.

Comment: Is the .fs file part of a .fsproj project? I wonder if that has an effect.

Comment: @libertyernie:  Both files are the default script and source files created in a new F# library project.

Comment: Are you using .Net Core? There are some issues with type providers that can be worked around with MSBuild magic...

Comment: Can you copy your code from script, compile it and run it?

Comment: @AlexanderM:  Yes, it compiles without error if I copy the code into a new project's script file. My only experience with script files is running tests on my source file code within the IDE, and I'm very much an amateur, so please help me understand... Is there a reason that a script file can't be *the* library file if I just want to serve up some predefined queries to another program? (This may have been the question I should've asked to begin with.)

Comment: @J.Hopkins, not really sure what do you mean. If your script file  contains only functions/classes you should be able to copy it to the *.fs file and make it library. However, what I was really trying to see if you are having a case of FSharp.Core used to build the provider being different from the one that you are using in the project. Can you add "main" function to your code and say print a records count from some table in your db, compile it as F# console application and run it from command line. Whether it would blow up with exception or show the count let me know

Comment: @AlexanderM: I run into the same issue for a console application as it runs on a .fs file. It immediately highlights the missing properties of the GetDataContext method, and won't compile. I tried this in a new console application that used Framework 4.5.1 which uses FSharp Core 4.5.2. The original post was edited to include the attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my purposes, this issue is resolved without any changes to the code.

I switched from "SQLProvider" (1.1.58, R. McKinlay et. al.) to "SQLProvider.Signed.1.0.40" (Niki Wiles).

Now, the properties work (show up) for the GetDataContext() method in my source file.